# Assign a datetime value if a datetime parameter is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I have an SSRS report that has, among others, start and end date parameters.  For both start and end date, an option NULL can be set.  The rule is that if a start date is null then the data retrieved starts from the beginning of time.  If the end date is null, then it is set to today's date.  This is what I'm trying to do here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytab 
WHERE (Start >= CASE @From 
                   WHEN NULL 
                      THEN DATEADD(year, -100, @From)
                END) 
  AND (End <= CASE @To
                 WHEN NULL THEN GETDATE()
              END)
```

As a test, I declare variables @From and @To in my query, set them to NULL and run it on SSMS.

What I'm trying to achieve is to say if @From is null, set the value to 100 years ago and compare it to the mytab field 'Start' . Likewise, if @To is null set it to today's date and compare with 'End'.  However this doesn't return any data.  It's obviously wrong so what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Hi, please provide (1) Queries to CREATE your tables including indexes. (2) Queries  to INSERT sample data. (3) The desired result given the sample, as text or image of excel for example. (4) A short description of the business rules, and how you got 1-2 of the results. (5) Which version of SQL Server you are using (this will help to fit the query to your version).

Comment: Have you tried using the `CASE WHEN @From IS NULL THEN ...` syntax?

Comment: You can simply `coalesce` values, e.g. `Coalesce( @To, Cast( GetDate() as Date ) )`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use CASE statements here, as we can make use of ISNULL or COALESCE.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytab 
WHERE Start >= ISNULL( @From , DATEADD(year, -100, GETDATE()) ) 
  AND End   <= ISNULL( @To   , GETDATE() )
```

Answer (score 0):

The CASE syntax doesn't resolve the NULLs like you want.

```
DECLARE @TEST AS VARCHAR(10)

SET @TEST = NULL

SELECT CASE WHEN @TEST IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEST1, 
       CASE @TEST WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEST2
```

Result is 1 for TEST1 and 0 for TEST2 - not 1 and 1 as expected.

```
SELECT * from mytab WHERE (Start >= CASE WHEN @From IS NULL THEN DATEADD(year, -100, @From) END) 

AND (End <= CASE WHEN @To IS NULL THEN GETDATE() END)
```

Answer (score 0):

A *simple* [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression `when` clause cannot match `null`, but you could test for it using [`is null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in a *searched* `case`: `case when @From is NULL then Cast( '1900-01-01' as Date ) else @From end`. Note that an `else` clause supplies a value if none of the `when` clauses match.

A tidier solution for your issue is to use [`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select *
  from MyTab
  where Coalesce( @From, Cast( '1900-01-01' as Date ) ) <= [Start] and
    [End] <= Coalesce( @To, Cast( GetDate() as Date ) );
```

Note that the value is cast to a `date` to eliminate the time-of-day.